# Find NFA for the language $L_1$ of all # that can be replaced by string of size 3 that would be in language $L$

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let $L$ be a regular language, and let
$$
L_1 = \{u_1\#u_2\# \dotsm \#u_n \mid ∃v_1,v_2,…,v_{n-1} \in \Sigma^3 \text{ such that } u_1v_1u_2 \dotsm v_{n-1}u_n \in L \}
$$
where $\# \notin \Sigma$.

For example: $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, $L = \{010101\}$, $L_1 = \{\#\#, 01\#1, 0\#01\}$.

My thought of the process was to try to validate by this logic.
Let's say I get the word $z = 01\#1$.
Then I check how many characters I passed before reaching $\#$, if I passed $n \leqslant 2$ then $u_1 = 01$,
and I send it to $L$ automata for validation.
Then I skip $\#$ and continue with the same logic.
I'm not sure my solution is working, and I can't think of a way to draw it.

Comment: You haven't told us what you want to do or show with $L_1$.

Comment: I would check if the word end with Ui for some i, and accept her. Which mean I would use to accept state of L if there's no more chars to read.

Comment: I have edited your question, which already had three close votes, to avoid it to be closed. I hope it is easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following construction should work. Start with a finite automaton $\cal A$ for $L$ and, for each path $p_0 \xrightarrow{a_1} p_1 \xrightarrow{a_2} p_2 \xrightarrow{a_3} p_3$ in $\cal A$, add a new transition $p_0 \xrightarrow{\#} p_3$. The resulting non deterministic automaton recognises $L_1$.